# google.maps.event.addDomListener mousedown on Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

got some problem with this code. The map did not become "undraggable" on Firefox immediately after mousedown on div, but on Chrome is ok.

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(div,'mousedown',function(e) {

    console.log("draggable START ", map.get('draggable') );
    map.set('draggable', false);
    console.log("draggable END", map.get('draggable') );
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   

});
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/benderlio/njyeLujs/

FF version is 54.0.1 windows 10
On chrome the map is not draggable after mouse down on white box, but on FF you can move the map and the white box on mousedown

Thanks.

Comment: Only adding to comment that I have found the exact same thing. I tried adding it to different panes and setting the draggable option in different ways; all had the same effect. It seems to not fire until mouseup on FF, but mousedown on Chrome.

Comment: @PaulThomasGC I solved the problem with mouseover/mouseout, but still want to find out why it is not working with mousedown

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have? Tested your code and it works for me.

Comment: I have the 54.0.1 version of firefox and the code works perfectly for me (like 'mouseup') event.

Comment: @S.P.H.I.N.X,  my version of FF is 54.0.1 and the map did not become "undraggable". On chrome the map is not draggable after mouse down on white box, but on FF you can move the map and the white box on mousedown

Comment: @Berkay  FF version is 54.0.1

Comment: Did you try setting `draggable` false inside div's `click` function?

Comment: I simply think you have found a bug, I've looked for existing ones, you may wish to post it : https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/76561

Comment: @Berkay yes, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/vr2ry5od/ still got the same result.

Comment: Does event fire after click? Any error at console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be stopping you from setting draggable on mousedown or mouseup other functions such as alert, etc work fine. Since draggable is only active when the mouse is down you can use mouseover/mouseout to workaround this bug. The following is working fine in firefox 54.0.1

```
var map, dragtoggle = true, div;

    function initMap() {

        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: 42.418664992,
                lng: -71.104832914
            },
            zoom: 13,
        });

            //creating the class to exntend the google map OverlayView class
            function MapLocationIcon(id,lat,lng,title,icon_class){
                this.lat = lat;
                this.lng = lng;
                this.title = title; //eg. A,B,C.D
                this.icon_class= icon_class; //the position of the spritesheet for the icon background
                this.pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
            }

            //make a copy of the OverlayView to extend it
            MapLocationIcon.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
            MapLocationIcon.prototype.onRemove= function(){}

            //prepare the overlay with DOM
            MapLocationIcon.prototype.onAdd= function(){
                div = document.createElement('DIV');
                function toggleDrag(){
                    if(dragtoggle == true){
                        map.set('draggable', false);
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        dragtoggle = false;

                    } else if(dragtoggle == false){
                        map.set('draggable', true);
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        dragtoggle = true;
                    }
                }
                function DragSwitch(){
                    $(div).css( "cursor", "auto");
                    dragtoggle = "disabled";
                }
                div.addEventListener('mouseover',toggleDrag,false);
                div.addEventListener('mouseout',toggleDrag,false);
                div.addEventListener('mousedown',DragSwitch,false);
                $(div).addClass('map_icon').addClass(this.icon_class);
                $(div).css( "background-color","white");
                $(div).css( "width","200px");
                $(div).css( "height","200px");
                $(div).css( "cursor", "grab");
                $(div).text(this.title);

                var panes = this.getPanes();
                panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div);

                /*
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(div,'mouseover',function(e) {
                        map.set('draggable', false);
                        console.log("draggable START ", map.get('draggable') );
                });
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(div,'mouseout',function(e) {
                        map.set('draggable', true);
                        console.log("draggable START ", map.get('draggable') );
                });
                */
            }

            //set position
            MapLocationIcon.prototype.draw = function(){
                var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
                var position = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.pos);
                var panes = this.getPanes();
                panes.overlayImage.style.left = position.x + 'px';
                panes.overlayImage.style.top = position.y - 30 + 'px';
            }

            //to use it
            var icon = new MapLocationIcon('id', 42.418664992,-71.104832914, 'AAA', 'gold');
            icon.setMap(map);
    }

  $("body").on("click", "#dis", function() {

        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        dragtoggle = "disabled";
        $(div).css( "cursor", "auto");
  });
  $("body").on("click", "#en", function() {

        map.setOptions({draggable: true});
        dragtoggle = true;
      $(div).css( "cursor", "grab");
  });


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```